# How to evaluate 2 strings in ASP.NET C# WebMethod return in JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webmethod

I have a WebMethod that updates an SQL database based on parameters passed from a ASP.NET button.  On success the WebMethod returns the state and is used to show or hide a div.  However the Javascript condition always evaluates as "Yes" even though "No" is passed back.

Control:

```
<telerik:RadButton
        TabIndex="1"
        ID="Updated"
        runat="server"
        ButtonType="ToggleButton"
        ToggleType="Checkbox"
        AutoPostBack="false"
        OnClientToggleStateChanged="ButtonSelect"
        CommandArgument="Updated" 
        CommandName="Updated">
             <ToggleStates>
                  <telerik:RadButtonToggleState
                          Text="No" 
                          PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadio"> 
             </telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
             <telerik:RadButtonToggleState
                 Text="Yes" 
                 PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadioChecked"> 
             </telerik:RadButtonToggleState>
        </ToggleStates>
   </telerik:RadButton>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ButtonSelect(button, args) {
        var state = args.get_currentToggleState().get_text();
        var whois = args.get_commandName();

        PageMethods.ButtonWebMethod(state, whois, onSucess, onError);

        //edited Stack Overflow Quetion here to == from =:
        function onSucess(returnstate) {
            if ((whois == "Updated") && (returnState == "Yes"))
            {
                $("#updateChoiceDIV").show();
                alert(returnstate + "Yep");
            }
            else if ((whois == "Updated") && (returnState == "No"))
            {
                $("#updateChoiceDIV").hide();
                alert(returnstate + "Nope");
            }
        }
        function onError(result) {
            alert('Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later.');
        }
    }
</script>
```

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string ButtonWebMethod(string state, string whois)
{
    string returnState = state;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["FieldName"] = whois;
    if (state == "Yes")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["" + whois + ""] = "True";
    }
    else if (state == "No")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["" + whois + ""] = "False";
    }
    string strConnString = WebConfigurationManager.
                                ConnectionStrings["gatorConnectionString"].
                                ConnectionString;
    try
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE [User] SET " + 
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["FieldName"] + "='" + 
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["" + whois + ""] + 
                        "' WHERE Id = '" + HttpContext.Current.Session["newID"] + 
                        "' ";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Update Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
    }
    return returnState;
}
```

And yes I'm not great at Javascript so be kind....

Comment: `=` is assignment which will always be true.  `==` and `===` is equality.  You have typos in your expressions.

Comment: I have tried == too even with just returnstate yes/no and could not get it to work but I'll try again. Thanks!

Comment: When I add == to the JQuery I don't even get the alert anymore. The WebMethod still updates the database but no alerts function.

Comment: Update your question please to show what you changed.  Also remember that you can add `console.log(literal|variable|expression)` in your logic at pretty much any point to see in the console what is going on. Ex. `console.log(returnState); console.log(returnState == "Yes");`

Comment: Oh! lol, i just noticed another typo.  You are passing in `returnstate` but checking `returnState`.  Case is sensative on variables.

Comment: Crap! Testing now Taplar...

Comment: That did it.  Now I feel really stupid! Thanks Taplar.

Comment: @Taplar if you answer I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Also that console tip is gold thanks Taplar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so a couple issues were found through the comments.

- Assignment (`=`) will typically return as true

This is because the result of an assignment is the value you set to it, which is typically not a falsy value.

```js
var x;
var y;

if (x = 1) { console.log(true); }
if (y = 0) {} else { console.log(false); }
```

The correct way to compare values is to use `===` or `==`.  If you expect, and require, that the two variables have the same type (compairing string to string or number to number) then you should use the `===` version.  If, however, you wish to allow the logic to coerce the values to be the same type (such as compairing 1 to "1") then you should use `==` and javascript will coerce them to the same type before compairing.

- `returnstate` != `returnState`

The second issue was that the argument `returnstate` was being provided to the function, however the inner logic was referencing `returnState` which didn't match the case of the previous variable, so it would have been `undefined` for all the expressions.